# Ho to install the Lightning Component "Filter List - View and sort records from standard and custom objects" from AppExchange

Tags: lightning-aura-components, permissions, appexchange, package-install

I'm trying to install this free component provided by Salesforce https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000qD5VEAU into a brand new Developer Org (Partner Developer Edition) located on EU5.

As an unfortunate after logging into AppExchange and clicking on the green "Get it Now" button, I get only

> Oops! Looks like you don't have permission to install apps.
>
> To keep your Salesforce secure, only system administrators have
>   permission to install apps or components. Please contact your
>   Salesforce system administrator to install this app or component.
>
> Or if you're feeling adventurous, sign up for a new free trial of
>   Salesforce so you can install and try out the app or component on your
>   own.

[image]

However I'm pretty sure to be Administrator on the Org (I'm the one and only Admin-User on the Org and have spun it myself...)

Any Idea on how to get this component installed is welcome!

Comment: Does that org have a custom My Domain enabled and deployed?

Comment: @Peter no, I have no custom My Domain enabled. Is that required? I would prefer to go without for many reasons...

Comment: As of Winter 16, My Domain is required for every org, for any custom Lightning Comonents feature: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/10/important-change-to-lightning-components-in-winter-16.html

Comment: Granted, that error is not very helpful. Can you capture the failure error for me in a screen shot and email it to me, @UweHeim. I'd like to suggest we make that failure error more intuitive.

Comment: Shoot. Kind of a shot in the dark on my part. Is that all the information the failure gives? Can you install  using API deploy? (Same user, same source/dest orgs.)

Comment: @Peter : unfortunately that message is really all I get... how does API-deploy work when I only have an AppExchange link? I did this only for my own managed packages and it needs the namespace and version information like in the ant-script `<installPackage namespace="Whatever" version="x.y" username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" server="${sf.server}"/>` - on https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000qD5VEAU there is neither Namespace nor Version specified, so I have no idea on how to test.

Comment: @Peter Screenshot added into the question.

Comment: Using workbench, I would think you'd be able to retrieve the package, then deploy. But I've done precious little with managed packages. So I am a little in the dark at this point. And that error is perplexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this component is obsolete to be installed from the AppExchange, because in the description it says:

> Filter List is a standard Lightning Component available in Lightning
>   App Builder. No need to install - find it in Lightning App Builder in
>   Setup. Easily display records from standard and Custom Objects from
>   any list view.

If this interpretation is right and in order to avoid confusions, Salesforce should do one of the following:

- remove that listing OR
- remove the "Get it now"-Button OR
- provide a meaningful error-message

Answer (score 0):

In Winter 16, for purposes of increased security, we now require a custom My Domain fourth-level domain for any org using custom Lightning Components functionality.

This information is in the [release notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_lightning_cruc.htm?edition=&impact=).

The developer relations team also [blogged](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/10/important-change-to-lightning-components-in-winter-16.html) about it recently.

Comment: Unfortunately after enabling and deploying the my Domain, there is exactly no change in the result. I still get the same error messages (plus I'm kind of unhappy with the my-domain itself, but what wouldn't we do all for security)